# Detect updates to AWS StepFunctions State Machine definition inside a Choice state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, continuous-deployment, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

This is a really good pattern for restarting very-long running state machine executions based on an iteration count so we don't breach the Standard quotas of 1 year execution time and 25k events - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-continue-new.html

[image]

**My Question: Is it possible to detect if the state machine definition has changed (since the start of the execution) in a Choice state? For eg., in the IsCountReached state above.**

We are planning to handle the State Machine creation and updation using AWS CDK. This would enable us to completely automate the deployments to State Machines, instead of manually killing the execution and restarting it after changes to the State Machine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such thing. It does not really make sense either, since a state machine is run on a "version" of your state machine definition. When you change your definition (new version), you typically don't want running processes to be influenced by that, since that might have unexpected consequences.

That said, you should be able to build something like this fairly easy: build a Lambda function that finds currently running state machines, stops them and restarts them. You invoke this Lambda function as part of your deployment process, if your definition changed.

This way, if your deployment contains changes to your state machine, all your currently running state machines would be restarted and then use the new definition.

Comment: I would argue that the ability to find if the current "version" has become stale would be very helpful for State Machines which run for several months (typically in a loop).

Comment: Your suggestion to stop executions and restart as a part of the deployment is interesting. But in some cases, we might not want to invoke StopExecution abruptly; but rather let the state machine do it by itself.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Maybe. But typically you want [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). That's why I'd rather have an external "controller" (e.g. Lambda etc) that keeps track of that and handles those cases instead of the step function handling this.

Comment: @NaveenKumar If you don't want to immediately stop the execution and want to hand over responsibility to the step function, you could set a simple flag in a boolean SSM parameter (e.g. `should_restart = true`). The step function then has a step that checks this parameter and if it is set to `true`, it "restarts" itself when "it thinks" it is the right time. This flag could be set during the deployment using the AWS CLI.

Comment: Couldn't separation of concerns be achieved by having nested Step Functions, where the outer SFN acts as a controller?

Comment: @NaveenKumar Yes, if the outer step function is only _concerned_ with controlling or "orchestrating" the child step functions.

Answer (score 1):

DescribeStateMachine doesn't return updateDate but DescribeStateMachineForExecution returns it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeStateMachineForExecution.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was thinking about parsing and finding the diff between the entire definition returned by DescribeStateMachine and DescribeStateMachineForExecution. Adding metadata to the comments is much simpler.

Comment: I wonder why updatedDate is not returned by DescribeStateMachine. Quite a bummer.

Comment: @NaveenKumar I'd rather use a hash of the definition (`sha1(myDefinition.json)`) instead of doing a diff. As soon as you change the definition, the hash will change and you know there was an update. This should be a lot easier than a diff.

Comment: I will raise this to AWS Step Functions team.

Comment: Naveen Kumar, @Jens: I updated my answer. DescribeStateMachineForExecution has updateDate data.